# Place detail "place.opening_hours" not returning data for all markers

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, undefined-symbol

I am having an issue where I make a request to the Places Libray from Google Maps JavaScript API for Place Details, but the response is not returning data under the opening_hours object for all markers, only some of them. I have checked and those markers do mark actual places from my text search and return data for the other fields, and I checked on Google Maps Native App of those places returning "undefined" for the opening_hours and they do show opening and closing hours. Here is some code to better understand what I mean:

map.ts:

```
//Request for all places based on query search
var request = {
  location: this.myLocation,
  radius: '400',
  query: "McDonalds"
};

// Callback function for places
function callback(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
  for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    let placeLoc = results[i].geometry.location;
    scopeObj.addMarker(results[i], placeLoc);
  }
}
};
let service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
service.textSearch(request, callback);

//Request for place details of each place, (this would loop through all place ids stored in an array
var request = {
  placeId: details.place_id,
  fields: ['name', 'formatted_address', 'formatted_phone_number', 'opening_hours',]
};

function callback(place, status) {
if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
  console.log(place.opening_hourse); 
/* Returns Object object if data is found, 
   returns undefined otherwise, question is why 
   if status returns OK for all places that have 
   been marked with markers on the map? */
}
}

let service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
service.getDetails(request, callback);
```

Comment: Can you provide example of place ID that demonstrates this issue? What type has this place in places search response?

Comment: Its a place by search query, so not a place type, but by keyword like for example searching for all McDonalds (that's not what I search for in my app) I would then place markers for all the results which I did and then request for the places details. I will update the code. I believe that there may be an issue with the place details on Google's side because those places returned in a place request are valid McDonald's restaurants. I then do a place details request on each place returned by query, however it seems that the place.opening_hours field does not return data for some of the places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using my own implementation of the API I am receiving opening_hours information from various places responses. I've omitted all the other fluff, but this is a Place Details request I've done and can repeat on numerous businesses and still get info.

```
   {
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : { 
         OMITTED
      "name" : "McDonald's",
      "opening_hours" : {
         "open_now" : true,
         "periods" : [
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 0,
                  "time" : "1700"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 0,
                  "time" : "0800"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 1,
                  "time" : "2100"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 1,
                  "time" : "0800"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 2,
                  "time" : "2100"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 2,
                  "time" : "0800"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 3,
                  "time" : "2100"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 3,
                  "time" : "0800"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 4,
                  "time" : "2100"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 4,
                  "time" : "0800"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 5,
                  "time" : "2100"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 5,
                  "time" : "0800"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 6,
                  "time" : "1700"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 6,
                  "time" : "0800"
               }
            }
         ],
         "weekday_text" : [
            "Monday: 8:00 AM – 9:00 PM",
            "Tuesday: 8:00 AM – 9:00 PM",
            "Wednesday: 8:00 AM – 9:00 PM",
            "Thursday: 8:00 AM – 9:00 PM",
            "Friday: 8:00 AM – 9:00 PM",
            "Saturday: 8:00 AM – 5:00 PM",
            "Sunday: 8:00 AM – 5:00 PM"
         ]
      },
    OMITTED
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

The only difference I can see with your implementation and mine is that you're specifying which fields you'd like in your request.

You can try retrieving all fields rather than specifically requesting the fields like you've done:

```
var request = {
  placeId: details.place_id,
};
```

Fields is an optional parameter, and could be causing you issues.

Comment: If you still encounter the issue, it might be worth sharing the ID you're testing against to see if myself or any other users also see the issue. That way we can chalk it up to a data issue with Google (which can happen.)

Comment: It may be a data issue with Google, but I am continuing my testing, I will let you know if your solution works.

Comment: I had a similar problem and removing the `fields` parameter fixed it. As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlaceOpeningHours.isOpen) suggests, `utc_offset_minutes` needs to be included in the list of fields for `isOpen()` to work.

Comment: What is the coordinate you used? I wish to see it as it looks like now.